# Inline dynamically change background image React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to learn React using movieDB. Each time a user searches a movie the background image should update.  However, it states I have an unexpected token.  What am I missing here?

```
class Movie extends Component {

var styles = {
    var imgURL = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/' + this.props.movie.poster_path;
    backgroundImage: 'url(' + imgUrl + ')',
    backgroundPosition: "center",
    backgroundSize: "cover"
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="Movie" style={styles}>
            <div>
                <img src={'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/' + this.props.movie.poster_path} />
            </div>
            <strong>{this.props.movie.tagline}</strong>
            <h3>{this.props.movie.title}</h3>
            <p>{this.props.movie.overview}</p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

Comment: I recommend you to use a linter eslinter in that case

Answer (score 0):

`var imgUrl` inside the object definition...

And yeah the whole block should go inside the render method

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
A community to help not criticize...

```
    var styles = {
        backgroundImage: `url(https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${this.props.movie.poster_path})`,
        backgroundPosition: "center",
        backgroundSize: "cover"
    }
```